# File Sharing Methods

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, permissions, network-share, file-sharing

So, I've been looking around, and haven't found any information that lays out the differences between the two file sharing areas in the `Folder Properties` `Sharing` tab, as in the image below. There seem to be two independent lists, and when going through the `Share and Storage Manager` on the server, only the advanced information shows. I just wanted a little more insight into what each configuration affects, and how they interact with eachother. (Note, I understand there is an interplay between NTFS and Sharing permissions, and I don't think is the same issue)

[image]

Essentially, my question is this... what is the difference between Option 1 and Option 2?

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference.

The first creates a new share (you can edit one) and automatically configures the share permissions to System and your current user.
The second allows you to manage the share (permissions, remove, offline files, etc.).

Comment: Does the top edit NTFS and share permissions?

Comment: Share permissions, I think if you share the same folder twice it changes the previous share permissions. As for NTFS, it doesn't change them. Also, note that if you don't have NTFS permissions over a folder, you can't share it...